# How can access a image file stored in my sd card

Tags: android, cordova, sd-card

I am working on phonegap with an Android project. I want to upload a file that is stored in my sd card to a server.

I want to be able to get a file that is stored in my assets folder.

```
**FileTransfer.upload(imageURI, "http://http://192.168.1.214/MusicApplication/welcome.php", win, fail, options);**
```

then please suggest me what should **imageURI** in above function if my image is stored in assets folder.

Comment: What's up with the display of this whole post as code?  I tried editing it to add backquotes at the beginning and end of the HTML, but it didn't work.  Is this a bug in our web application?

Comment: No sir this is correct but we have to import some java script file. Sir please suggest me how can i access a image which is stored in my local file system. i am unable to give proper path of that image which is to be upload. i have stored my image file in the assets folder of my project.

Comment: @Don Quixote Code samples are indented at 4 spaces from the left, so any text that you want not to include in the code block should be indented at less than that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this for [Using External Storage](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesExternal).

Depending upon your API level, use `getExternalFilesDir()` or `getExternalStorageDirectory()` to find the file you are looking for.

Comment: this is the solution of my problem:-   var options = new FileUploadOptions();
   options.fileKey="file";
     options.fileName=document.getElementById('txtFileName').value;
     options.mimeType="audio/mpeg";
 
    var params = new Object();
    params.value1 = "test";
    params.value2 = "param";
 
    options.params = params;
 
    var ft = new FileTransfer();
   ft.upload(fileName, "http://192.168.1.214/MusicApplication/upload.php", win, fail, options);

Answer (score 0):

his is the solution of my problem:-

```
var options = new FileUploadOptions();
 options.fileKey="file"; 
options.fileName=document.getElementById('txtFileName').value; options.mimeType="audio/mpeg"; var params = new Object();
 params.value1 = "test"; 
params.value2 = "param"; 
options.params = params; 
var ft = new FileTransfer();
 ft.upload(fileName, "192.168.1.214/MusicApplication/upload.php";, win, fail, options);
```